# The level of 'weakness' and 'strength'

Tags: word-choice

I'm organizing the weaknesses and strengths of my research project, and suddenly an idea came up to my mind that it'll be fairly handy to summarize the weaknesses and strengths using some standardized values. I would like to call these in concise terms, but I cannot find appropriate terms to describe '*the (significance) level of weakness/strength*'. Could anyone recommend some terms suitable to use in this situation?

Comment: We often give **weight** to specific factors, to indicate their relative importance. But when talking about *general* weaknesses and strengths of a project, the idea of "significance *level*" seems unduly and unworkably precise. You could talk about "minor" and "major" weaknesses, or "signficant" and "insignificant" weaknesses.

Comment: "Impact" strong items have a high impact, weak items have a low impact.

Comment: For what it's worth, you might like to note that Anglophones very rarely refer to [*the weaknesses and strengths*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+weaknesses+and+strengths%2Cthe+strengths+and+weaknesses&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20weaknesses%20and%20strengths%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20strengths%20and%20weaknesses%3B%2Cc0) of anything. Per that NGram, it's nearly always ***the strengths and weaknesses***. Just don't ask me *why*, but as a native speaker I can't avoid noticing the "unusual" phrasing there.

Comment: On reflection, perhaps it's because when we have [good news and bad news](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22good+news+and+bad+news%22) (which itself is *far* more common than having [bad news and good news](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22bad+news+and+good+news%22), we always like to get the good stuff out first. It's always [pros and cons](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pros+and+cons%2Ccons+and+pros&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpros%20and%20cons%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccons%20and%20pros%3B%2Cc0), not cons and pros.

Comment: After thinking a while, I came up with the terms 'criticality' and 'beneficiality'. I think 'criticality' is common enough, but I am not sure whether the term 'beneficiality' is as common as it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers These are [Siamese twins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_twins_(linguistics)) and reversing them is awfully fun. "If two people are wife and husband, they are friends through thin and thick. They'll stick together through high water and hell, whether it's raining dogs and cats or brimstone and fire. Even closer, though, is your own blood and flesh. With kin and kith, you mustn't be lukewarm — it's nothing or all..." :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to come up with nouns for this (the **degree** of weakness, the **level** of weakness...).

But those are hard to use with weakness and strength. When you can't quantify something directly, terms like that fail. A standardized form in a professional environment might say something like:

> Rate your strength in the following areas.         1   2   3   4   5
>   
> *Working with other people*                                                ✗
>   
> *Working independently*                                               ✗

Then you might say that the person's "strength is a three in the area of working independently" (or something equally far removed from everyday English).

In the end, I agree with  Tᴚoɯɐuo's comment:

> When talking about general weaknesses and strengths of a project, the idea of "significance level" seems unduly and **unworkably precise**.

Here are some ways to talk about various "degrees" on that scale.

> It's a **significant** weakness. We should factor it in.
>
> He has some **considerable** strengths in that area.
>
> That weakness is **negligible**. We can ignore it.
>
> She's **very** strong when it comes to logical deduction.
>
> One of your **biggest** strengths is your ability to remain calm in adversity.
>
> Oh, you brought dark chocolate? That's my **fatal** weakness.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of the following combinations to classify the level of your weaknesses or strengths:

1. High / Medium / Low
2. Advanced / Intermediate / Beginners
3. Maximum / Average / Minimum

You could also use numbers from 1 to 5 or 1 to 10 and mention somewhere the scale and the range of numbers you are using.

Comment: Thank for the recommendations. But actually, my question was about the term collectively indicating the scales such as 'Major / Minor weakness'. :)